# webAPI, casting object of type error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to developing webAPIs. I am not sure why this is not working:

```
public IEnumerable<Users> GetAll()
    {
        var UserAll = from c in dbc.Users select c;
        return (IEnumerable<Users>)UserAll;
    }
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Guild_Chat.User]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Guild_Chat.Models.Users]'.

can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to return `IEnumerable<User>` instead of `Users`.

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
{
    return dbc.Users;
}
```

The error message is self explanatory.You can't cast `IEnumerable<User>` to `IEnumerable<Users>`.

Comment: `from c in dbc.Users select c` is same as `dbc.Users`